# C++ maths not working as expected when running

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to do this C++ program which adds the natural numbers between two numbers. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, limit, sum = 0;
    char ch;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the initial number: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Enter the last number: ";
        cin >> limit;

        while (number <= limit) {
            sum += number;
            ++number;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The sum of all the numbers between the two number you entered is ==> " << sum;
        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Do you want to calculate again? y-YEs n-No: ";
        cin >> ch;
        cout << endl;
        
        if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N') {
            cout << "Thank you for using our program. Peace :)\n\n";
        }
    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Tried the numbers between from 1 to 10 it outputs 55 which is right. But when I tried the numbers from 1 to 11 it outputs 121 which is wrong. I am using visual studio 2019, I have tried to debug it with tracing, and there was no wrong output when I was watching the variables. The problem is only when the program is executed.

Can anyone help me please, I am a beginner.

Comment: This doesn't compile, post your real code.

Comment: Post whole code from first to last line.

Comment: Agreed, the code does not compile: [https://ideone.com/TrUIKu](https://ideone.com/TrUIKu)

Comment: My guess is you are actually using the do { loop and you forgot to reset sum. So the second time around it has the value from the first loop.

Comment: `sum` should be reinitialised to 0 for each new input

Comment: Okay I edited it to the whole code

Comment: You forgot to reset sum to 0 each loop.

Comment: missing `sum = 0;` before `while`, demo: https://godbolt.org/z/78M1cz so you where summing everything - earlier inputs too.

Comment: I just deleted the `do-while` and it worked properly, I wanted to use the `do-while` to repeat the program as much as the user wants to. How can I do that, please?

Comment: A nice habit to acquire is declaring and initializing variables as close to their use as possible.

Comment: Move the code that calculates the sum into a separate function and call that function from the main loop. That way there's no way to go wrong with the initial value of `sum` -- either it always works or it never (well, hardly ever) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable declarations and initialization:

```
int number, limit, sum = 0;
```

all happen one time before you enter the loop. So you're actually keeping a running sum over multiple runs!

To fix this, you can just make sure to reset `sum` to 0 at the beginning of each loop:

```
do {
    sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter the initial number: ";
    // ...
```

Comment: Why not declare `sum` inside the loop as well?

Comment: @cigien that'd work too. Personally I prefer to declare variables once instead of re-declaring them every loop. But I also know ppl who prefer their variables are scoped to prevent mistakes.

Comment: Yes, that's the main reason I declare variables as close to their usage as possible. Also, it's more readable to me that way.